# Open Map AnnotationView from selectedRow in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapkit, mkannotationview

How can I place MKAnnotationView on specified annotation after I select tableview cell? Do I somehow need to call function mapView(_:didSelect:) within didSelectRowAtIndexPath of table view? Here is my didselectrow func. I did try with map.selectAnnotation within didselectrow, but returns nil.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let pin = filteredDetails[indexPath.row].coordinate

        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.009
        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.009

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pin.latitude, pin.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

       // mapView.selectAnnotation(customXibView as! MKAnnotation, animated: true)

        tableView.isHidden = true


        }
```

And this is my map didselect func.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        let meridianAnnotation = view.annotation as! Details

        let customXibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutVIew", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomAnnotationClass!

        customXibView?.address.text = meridianAnnotation.address
        customXibView?.phone.text = meridianAnnotation.phone

        let calloutFrame = view.frame
        customXibView?.frame = CGRect(x: (calloutFrame.size.width)-178.0, y: (calloutFrame.size.height)-220, width: 315, height: 166)


        customXibView?.blurOverlay.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        customXibView?.layer.masksToBounds = true


        let shadowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: (calloutFrame.size.width)-178.0, y: (calloutFrame.size.height)-220, width: 315, height: 154))
        shadowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        shadowView.layer.borderWidth = 7.0
        shadowView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        shadowView.alpha = 1.0
        shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4.0, height: 4.0)
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 13.0

        view.insertSubview(shadowView, at: 0)

        view.addSubview(customXibView!)

        mapView.setCenter((view.annotation?.coordinate)!, animated: true)


    }
```

Comment: mapView.selectAnnotation only works when you passed annotation object which is already added in mapview

Comment: well, my objects are already all added to the map, when I press on cell It centers map on related annotation, all I want is, additionally for callout view to pop-up as if I selected it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let pin = filteredDetails[indexPath.row].coordinate

        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.009
        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.009

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pin.latitude, pin.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

      mapView.selectAnnotation(filteredDetails[indexPath.row], animated: true)

        tableView.isHidden = true


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`,
 You are passing  `customXibView` instead of that

You have to search for Annotation associated with that tableview

Once you find it, you can tell it, to select it by using:

`mapView.selectAnnotation`

You can use  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980302/4601900 answer to search annotation from `MapView`